# When I sign Android Project, it is doesnt work

Tags: android, eclipse, sign, vitamio

I'm using Eclipse for sign and I'm using VitamioCoreLibrary and VitamioPlayerLibrary at my project. When I sign my Android Project then try it is doesnt work. But if I use MyProject\Bin\MyProject.apk file then transfer my phone and try it is work. But I must sign the apk file. How can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesnt work"? Can you successfully install the signed apk or does it fail when trying to install it? If you already have a debug version of your app on your phone you must uninstall before trying to install the signed / release version. The same is true the other way around (uninstall release version before installing new debug version).

Comment: Hi, doesnt work mean is : I can install and start app then show message "initializing decoders" and a few minute after return main screen. so When I press play button again return main menu. I can successfully install the signed apk file. I'm always unistall release version before installing new dedebug version. Thanks.

Comment: Post the logcat output showing what's happening when you try to start the app.

Comment: I can not see error message my phone debug or Run mode(Android 2.3.6) but I can see error message Emulator (Android 4.4.2) I'm dont sure same error. Error Message :03-27 17:10:42.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 17:10:42.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): Process: com.radyofeza:vitamio, PID: 1908
03-27 17:10:42.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-27 17:10:42.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):  at io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(LibsChecker.java:40)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like u need to create a Keystore:

Here is a tutorial on that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1j4prh3NAZE&t=297s